# Android studio gradle build issues new appcompat / buildtools

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Every time when new updates for

appcompat-v4,
appcompat-v7 or
buildToolsVersion arrives

and updated in my application i have to spend like a full day fixing all kind of build errors. 
For example i have changed the buildToolsVersion from 23.0.1 to 23.1.1
rebuilding the project results in loads of errors like

```
Error:(55, 35) error: package com.google.android.gms.plus does not exist
```

I know for sure i have included the gcm dependency. So i start cleaning and deleting files. After a while i manage to rebuild, but then i get an error saying:

```
error: package android.support.v7.internal.widget does not exist
```

And this keeps on going for a while.

To me the whole gradle is extremely hard to work with in large projects (many submodules, deps etc). Once you have it working it is fine, but its like a massive unstable structure ready to collapse once you apply a small change.

Anyone experienced similar issues and have found a way to make the migrations to newer versions easier?